# Перенести коммит из одной ветки в другую

Tags: git, контроль-версий

Каким образом в Git перенести отдельный коммит из одной ветки А в ветку Б? При этом коммит содержит файлы, которые были изменены в ветке Б.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

В Git есть специальная команда [`cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick), которая позволяет вставлять в текущую ветку изменения из любого коммита. Работает она так:

```
git cherry-pick test
```

Пример выше применяет последний коммит из ветки `test` в текущую ветку.

При желании, можно перенести более одного коммита за один раз. Например:

```
git cherry-pick 8fe1498 mega_fix~3 v1.0.1
```

Из примера выше видно, что на коммит можно сослаться сразу несколькими способами:

- Используя SHA хэш коммита (или его сокращенный вариант).
- Используя имя ветки (можно использовать синтаксис `^<N>` и `~<N>`).
- Используя тэг, которым помечен коммит.

Более подробная информация о том, как сослаться на коммит есть в [документации к Git](http://schacon.github.io/git/git-rev-parse.html#_specifying_revisions).

Стоит отметить, что в отличии от слияния ([`merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)) при `cherry-pick` переносятся только *изменения*, а не сам коммит полностью. При этом, в целевой ветке создается *новый* коммит (коммиты) содержащий необходимые изменения.

Comment: Всё ещё есть возможность написать более подробный ответ. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, спасибо за наводку. Сейчас подумаю, что еще можно добавить =)

Comment: Ничего не сказано, как потом выбросить коммит из ветки-источника.

Comment: @4per, а это уже совсем другая задача. Более того, не всегда нужно выбрасывать коммит после cherry-pick ;)

Comment: Видимо я неправильно понимаю значение слова "перенести", а также "перебросить" которое есть в вопросе, который @NickVolynkin жестко связал с этим (;

Comment: @4per, строго говоря, cherry-pick не переносит коммиты, а применяет отдельный коммит из какой-либо ветки к текущей. Потому задачу "удалить коммит" я рассматриваю отдельно. Для удаления коммита можно использовать `git reset --hard`, `git rebase -i`, `git branch` + `git branch -d` и еще много других вариантов. И, как я уже сказал, это тема для отдельного вопроса. Если он еще не поднимался на ru.SO, то самое время его задать ;)

Answer (score 9):

Посмотрите на git cherry-pick, например [тут](http://www.calculate-linux.ru/main/ru/git). Эта команда позволяет выдернуть определенный коммит с одной ветки и применить его к текущей ветке. При этом он станет новым коммитом. Ну и возможно потом нужно будет разрулить конфликты слияния.

Answer (score 4):

```
git cherry-pick <hash коммита>
```

> найдёт коммит по его хэшу sha1 и вольёт его в текущую ветку

Подробнее [тут](http://jeka.by/ask/198/git-transfer-commit-from-another-branch-cherry-pick/).